# Differences between gcc3 and gcc4 regarding uninitialized variables

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, initialization

We have a body of C++ code which is being ported from a RHEL4-based distro to RHEL-5-based.
It used to compile with g++ 3.4.3, and now compiles with g++ 4.1.2.
It turns out that there are local POD variables that are being used uninitialized, which is causing
failures under the new environment -- not surprising, since C++ rules say that local POD structures
are left uninitialized and therefore random.

I'm looking for an explanation of why this didn't bother us when compiled with 3.4.3,
but is now wreaking havoc with 4.1.2.  Is there maybe an obscure setting in
the specs of gcc3 that helpfully initialized local POD variables?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653555/can-g-fill-uninitialized-pod-variables-with-known-values

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is almost the same question.  I just can't believe this code ran for years without exposing the problem.  I know it's better to be lucky than good, but I'm not accustomed to being that lucky :-).

Comment: @BobLied - In my book it's *not* lucky if UB allows you to get away with doing something without noticing, it's *unlucky* because it's hiding a problem for the future when you've forgotten all about that chunk of code...

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behavior is, as the name implies, undefined. The compilers don't have to explain why they do what they do, they don't have to do one thing consistently, and they don't have to have a *reason* for what they do.

The way compilers typically treat undefined behavior is to ignore it. There was never a GCC developer who sat down and said "let's write some code for how GCC handles uninitialized variables". Whatever happens to them happens as a result of falling through all the *other* code in GCC. So new versions of the compiler might do different things with uninitialized variables, not because the compiler handles them differently, but because it never intentionally handled them *at all*.

Comment: Hehe, yes, asking the question why two compilers behave differently for undefined behaviour seems to answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps by compiling your code with a more recent version (e.g. *4.6.1*) of g++ and by asking for all warnings (using *-Wall -Wextra*), then by hacking the source code till no more warnings are issued, you could improve the situation