# Controlling the fill value (e.g. 0xCC) for uninitialized stack variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, memory

First, a bit of background: we have a framework that will run through a series of tests multiple times and ensure that the state is identical on each runthrough. This catches a number of cases that produce nondeterministic behavior, including ones caused by multithreading or sorting by pointer values. These tests run in Debug on Visual Studio 2008 (moving soon to 2010).

The problem: unfortunately, the tests don't catch usage of uninitialized variables as often as I'd like. Consider these cases:

```
struct Foo{ int m_a; int m_b; };
void doStuff( struct Foo& f);
...
Foo* bar = new Foo();
// Uninitialized in ctor, but heap initialized to 0xCD,
// so appears "deterministic"
if (bar->m_a) 
{ ... }

Foo baz;
// may or may not initialize all of baz
// uninitialized members are left to 0xCC
doStuff( baz );
if (baz.m_b)
{ ... }
```

What I'd like to do is make the uninitialized values different on each runthrough to catch these cases, e.g. known garbage on the first run and 0 on the second one. That way any computations on unintialized members will give different results, and checking them in an `if` statement will also take the opposite branch.

I have control over the first case because we route `new` and `delete` through our own heap. However, I haven't been able to find any information on how to control the fill value for stack variables - is this possible at all? The closest question that I could find on here was [Can g++ fill uninitialized POD variables with known values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653555/can-g-fill-uninitialized-pod-variables-with-known-values), but that's for g++. I don't need a portable solution; a Visual Studio-specific trick will do just fine.

Note #1: I know that lint/Rational Purify/Valgrind/[insert static code analysis magic bullet] will catch this, and probably more robustly. But I'm looking for a small change I can make to our existing framework, and these will likely take more time to integrate than I'm prepared to spend, so please don't suggest these.

Note #2: We already have the warning level set to the max and warnings as errors turned on, which catches some cases of uninitialized variables, but this doesn't catch all the cases where the "doStuff" function forgets to initialize some of the struct.

Note #3: I'm not too worried about performance as this is already running in Debug, and is only used for internal testing.

Note #4: The same executable is used for the tests (run once in "write" mode, then again in "check" mode to compare results), so unfortunately different compile settings isn't an option at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing it is not an option.  An obvious way to cause a mismatch is to compare the results of the Debug build with a build that was made without /RTC in effect.  Like the Release build, the one that really needs to be tested.

Comment: The system is currently structured so that the same executable runs each test. I should have mentioned that before.

Comment: Isn't it easiest to give everything a default constructor that sets each member to `MAGIC_VAL`? And do several debug tests with `MAGIC_VAL` set to different values.

Comment: or, the [/RTC1 flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @MooingDuck - it look like /RTC1 still misses some basic cases. Does it catch anything that warning level 4 (which we already have) doesn't?

Comment: @celion: Documentation says /RTC1 adds compiler warnings (which are part of Warning Level 4 already) and _also_ "Enables stack frame run-time error checking"  Read the link under the `s` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to figure out which code is doing the filling and patch it at runtime. If the dllversion is fixed, this should be a acceptible for a debug build. You probably need to be able to handle different dll load adresses, as they might be loaded at random locations for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I find the compiler can be very helpful in tracking down these sorts of problem using something like:

```
class checked_int_t {
    int i_;
public:
    checked_int_t(int const i) : i_ (i) { }
    operator int() const { return i_; }
};
```

Now your code might change to something like the following which will generate a compile time error when you allocate a Foo object because m_a is not initialised in the default constructor.

```
struct Foo{
    checked_int_t m_a;
    int m_b;
};
```

Note that you can do this incrementally to check for unitialised variables so you don't have to make big changes. Just find a variable you think is not being initialised properly and change its type. If you absolutely must set the value later, you could alternatively do something like:

```
class checked_int_t {
    int i_;
    bool set_;
public:
    checked_int_t() : set_ (false) { }
    checked_int_t(int const i) : i_ (i), set_ (true) { }
    operator int() const { assert(set_); return i_; }
};
```

You can use conditional compilation to get rid of the class for release mode.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
typedef int checked_int_t;
#else
class checked_int_t {
    int i_;
public:
    checked_int_t(int const i) : i_ (i) { }
    operator int() const { return i_; }
};
#endif
```